# Helicopter spawn scheme

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Can someone explain to me how the helicopters in GTA Online spawn (and also airplanes). I had a session yesterday, where it would keep spawning Titans on the Sandy Shores airfield, whereas on another session it would spawn the normal small airplane.

The same with the cargobob. Yesterday, everywhere I look, cargobobs. But today, checking the helipdas, it would offer me the Frogger. There has to be some scheme to when what spawns, does someone know anything about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's randomness mixed with rank that's about it. The higher level you are, the better the stuff that spawns, but it's still to some point random. So you won't only spawn nice vehicles vs only spawning shit ones

[taken from R* forum](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200242008-How-do-the-vehicle-spawns-work-in-GTA-Online-)

Comment: I don't really think there is randomness involved. To my experience it's level based, because at each of the spawn locations I can exactly tell which air vehicle will spawn before I go near. I can't tell on which level the vehicle switches, but for helicopters I'm only getting Buzzards everywhere. Except near the private docks west of the civilian airport, there I'll consistently spawn an Annihilator.

Comment: For me it's complete random. Sometimes I get a Buzzard, sometimes some other (don't know the names). I just found this one entry.

Comment: I'm still low level, always spawn Cargobob

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Then (I think) there are some higher leveled users in the spawn area...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the level of you (or the players in your presence) affects the type of helicopters and planes that spawn, if any at all.